# SSIS CSV and DB Table count Check

Tags: ssis

I need to compare my record count from csv file to the count of DB Table and if the record of csv file is higher then only i need to insert the records.

How can i perform this validation in SSIS Package ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Execute SQL Task count to find the number of records in the DB Table and store in a variable.

In Data Flow Task1
1. Read the .csv file and use the "Row Count" transformation to count the rows and store in a variable.

Link Data Flow Task 1 to Data Flow Task 2 with a condition and restraint whereby it only passes to Data Flow Task 2 when .csv row count <> DB Table Row count.

In Data Flow Task 2
1. Process the .csv file and up[date the DB Table